# Richfaces 4 autocomplete new value

Tags: user-interface, jsf, jsf-2, autocomplete, richfaces

I am trying to implement a dropdown+textbox kind of element in UI. Was using rich:autocomplete to achieve that. It worked, with one issue.

The client requirement is that the textbox should be able to take new values in it. i.e. If the values values are in the dropdown, it will take the dropdown values, otherwise it will take the new values entered.

Is there anyways to achieve that using rich:dropdown? Any other suggestion are also welcome. My application is using JSF2.0 + Richfaces 4.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement I can suggest you can use tag input widget, see the reference link url:http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/tag-input